# How to iterate over list of lists from text file- Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have text file which has list of lists like below.

**sample.txt Text file content **:

[["Sanjay", "Bangalore", "100"], ["Akshay", "Pune", "101"], ["Pranay", "Delhi", "102"]]

**Requirement**:

I have to iterate over each list in he above list and assign each item in list to variable.

Test Case

```
${FILECONTENT}=    Get File    sample.txt
Log to console    ${FILECONTENT}
: FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    ${FILECONTENT}
\    ${NAME}=   ${ELEMENT}[0] 
\    ${CITY}=   ${ELEMENT}[1] 
\    ${ID}=   ${ELEMENT}[2] 
\    Log to console    ${ELEMENT}
Log to console    For loop is over
```

I am not able to loop over content as its not treating content as list of lists.

Can any one help how to achieve this.

Comment: Is that file valid JSON, or just something that looks like JSON? Is it guaranteed to be parseable by a JSON parser?

Answer (score 3):

The example code you provided has a few issues. First, and foremost is that you need to convert the string to a list-in-list construction. Then you need to correctly iterate over it and lastly assign variables in the right way.

As there isn't a native keyword to allow for instant string to list-in-list conversion I created a custom keyword library for it and stored it as `List.py` in the same folder as your robot script:

```
import ast

class List(object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ConvertToListFromString(self, ListString):
        x = ast.literal_eval(ListString)
        return x
```

This library can then be utilized to create the functionality in robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    List

*** Test Cases ***
Sample
    ${FILECONTENT}=    Get File    sample.txt
    @{list}    Convert To List From String    ${FILECONTENT}

    Log to Console    ${EMPTY}

    : FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{list}
    \    ${NAME}     Set Variable   ${ELEMENT[0]} 
    \    ${CITY}     Set Variable   ${ELEMENT[1]} 
    \    ${ID}       Set Variable   ${ELEMENT[2]}
    \    
    \    Log to console    Name=${NAME}, City=${CITY}, Id=${ID}
```

This then results into:

```
Command: C:\Python27\python.exe -m robot.run -P C:\Eclipse\Workspace\ExternalList 
-s ExternalList.ExternalList C:\Eclipse\Workspace\ExternalList
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.0 (Python 2.7.9 on win32)
==============================================================================
ExternalList                                                                  
==============================================================================
ExternalList.ExternalList                                                     
==============================================================================
Sample                                                                
Name=Sanjay, City=Bangalore, Id=100
Name=Akshay, City=Pune, Id=101
Name=Pranay, City=Delhi, Id=102
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExternalList.ExternalList                                             | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
ExternalList                                                          | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Eclipse\Workspace\ExternalList\output.xml
Log:     C:\Eclipse\Workspace\ExternalList\log.html
Report:  C:\Eclipse\Workspace\ExternalList\report.html
```

It should be noted that reading files an converting them to code poses some security risks that need to be mitigated. The above code is therefore not Production ready.

Comment: Great use of `ast.literal_eval`, kudos! Taught me something I'm going to heavily (ab)use now in my sets :)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is valid JSON, you can convert the data to JSON and then iterate over the values very easily:

```
${FILECONTENT}=    Get File    sample.txt
${JSON}=  evaluate  json.loads($FILECONTENT)  json
:FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{JSON}
\    ${NAME}     Set Variable   ${ELEMENT[0]} 
\    ${CITY}     Set Variable   ${ELEMENT[1]} 
\    ${ID}       Set Variable   ${ELEMENT[2]}
\    Log to console    element: ${ELEMENT}
```

Note: the other statements in your FOR loop are incorrect. To set new variables you must call the [Set Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable) keyword. That is why I changed them in the example code.

Comment: This is I think the best solution for the presented problem as it doesn't require a new library.

Comment: Bryan Oakley and A. Kootstra Thank you very much. I have checked Bryan's code and its working perfectly for the requirement. Great help! Saved lot of my time.